# Sharepoint 2013: How to open a second modal window from a first modal window

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, modal-dialog

I am troubleshooting a Sharepoint 2010 page which has a button which brings up a modal window form, on this form is a second button which is supposed to bring up a second modal window with a related sub form.  When I click on the second button, it seems like the first modal window is preventing the second one from appearing.

The second button is defined in an .aspx form:

```
<td> <asp:Button ID="Button4" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" runat="server" Text="Assign Task To" OnClientClick="Javascript:OpenDialog12('/_layouts/QuickWebparts/TaskAssignedTo.aspx',600,400);return false;" /></td>
```

which calls the javascript function:

```
function OpenDialog12(_url, w, h) {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = _url;

    options.width = w;
    options.height = h;   

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Is it possible to open a second modal window from inside an existing modal window, in a nested sequence:  Main Page > Modal 1 > Modal 2  ?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? If so, what problems did you run into? If you havent, you should try it first and come back and ask for help if you run into problems.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?